# Unable to Upgrade Ubuntu 10 to 12 due to unauthenticated-sources-errors

Tags: upgrade

When upgrading to Ubuntu 12 from 10, I get this error messages:

```
2015-10-31 13:36:32,746 ERROR Unauthenticated packages found: 'accountsservice apparmor apt apt-transport-https apt-utils apt-xapian-index aptitude base-files bash bash-completion bind9 bind9-doc bind9-host bind9utils binutils bsdutils build-essential busybox-initramfs busybox-static ca-certificates cifs-utils consolekit coreutils cpio cron curl dbus dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dhcp3-client dhcp3-common dmidecode dmsetup dnsutils dosfstools dpkg dpkg-dev e2fslibs e2fsprogs ecryptfs-utils file fontconfig fontconfig-config fuse fuse-utils gamin ghostscript glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-keyring gnupg gnupg-curl gpgv grub-common gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs hdparm ifupdown initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts iproute iptables isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common krb5-locales language-selector-common libaccountsservice0 libappindicator3-1 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libarchive12 libart-2.0-2 libasn1-8-heimdal libasound2 libaudiofile1 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-glib1 libbind9-80 libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libck-connector0 libcomerr2 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdconf0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdns81 libdpkg-perl libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libecryptfs0 libelf1 libevent-2.0-5 libexif12 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libfuse2 libgail18 libgamin0 libgc1c2 libgck-1-0 libgcr-3-1 libgcr-3-common libgcrypt11 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglade2-0 libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnutls26 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port0 libgs9 libgs9-common libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgssglue1 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libgudev-1.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82 libjasper1 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg62 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb53 libkrb5support0 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 liblockfile-bin liblockfile1 liblua5.1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblwres80 liblzo2-2 libmagic1 libmount1 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-1d liborbit2 libpam-gnome-keyring libpango1.0-0 libparted0debian1 libpci3 libpciaccess0 libpcre3 libperl5.14 libpixman-1-0 libplymouth2 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libproxy1 libpython2.7 libroken18-heimdal libruby1.8 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsmbclient libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssl0.9.8 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-3 libtiff4 libudev0 libusbmuxd1 libuuid1 libwbclient0 libwind0-heimdal libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb1 libxcursor1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-sax-perl libxml2 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 linux-firmware linux-headers-3.2.0-92 linux-headers-3.2.0-92-generic linux-headers-server linux-image-3.2.0-92-generic linux-image-server linux-libc-dev linux-server login lsb-base lsb-release lvm2 make man-db mime-support mktemp mount mountall mtools multiarch-support ntfs-3g ntfsprogs ntp ntpdate openssh-client openssh-server openssl parted passwd patch pciutils perl perl-base perl-modules plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome ppp procps psmisc python python-apt python-apt-common python-central python-gi python-gobject python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal quota resolvconf rsyslog samba-common samba-common-bin shared-mime-info smbclient smbfs sqlite3 sudo sysv-rc sysvinit-utils tcpdump tzdata ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard udev udisks unzip update-manager-core upstart usbmuxd util-linux util-linux-locales uuid-runtime vim-common vim-gnome vim-gui-common vim-runtime vim-tiny w3m wget wpasupplicant x11-common x11-utils xkb-data'
```

Some suggested to amend the unauth.cfg file for AllowUnauthenticated=yes. But some were strongly against this as it might break our email server.

Could a wrong sources.list affect this? May I have the sources.list file from a working Ubuntu 10 as reference?

Comment: Honestly, what does this machine do? How hard would it be to just fresh install 16.04 and reconfigure everything?

Comment: Running Zimbra email server with hundreds of email accounts over over 2TB of email data. The time to migrate them and the downtime without email may not be acceptable to the users.

Comment: Oh. Oh God. I see why you want to upgrade.  I would still highly advise doing a fresh install if at all possible, because upgrades have the potential to do very weird things that may end up causing data loss. I've seen it happen before, and it's not fun to recover from.

Comment: If you have some spare hard drives on hand and want to play around a bit, you could fresh-install Ubuntu to a clean drive, install Zimbra to it, and just symlink over to your data folders. You wouldn't have to migrate your data over to places, but at least you can upgrade your server. Should be less downtime, too. Ideally, then, you'd also end up having a dedicated hard drive just for Zimbra e-mail data.

Comment: The upgrade of Ubuntu involve upgrade of Zimbra and upgrade of the database as well. I doubt the same data can be presented to both Ubuntu at the same time and there is no going back. And if this is on another server, will symlink works?

Comment: Let me clarify. If both your Zimbra install and your Ubuntu install are on the same server, you can just add a new hard drive containing a fresh install of 16.04. Then, just install Zimbra to the clean 16.04 and perform the DB upgrade. From there, just use mountpoints and the like to "move" the data over without ever copying everything. Essentially, your OS/Zimbra App will be on one hard drive, and your data will be on your other drives. I'm not sure about multi-server, as I've never really worked much with Zimbra in the past.

Comment: "may not be acceptable to the users" then dont? Install a 2nd server with 16.04 on it. Copy the history over to the new machine when you got all software installed and then start using that. Makes downtime minimal and less errorprone since you can test anything on the new machine before it goes live.

Comment: Not so simple with Zimbra, because as mentioned, the database will not be compatible without a proper upgrade at each level. Currently I'm running Zimbra 8 on Ubuntu 10.

1. Upgrade Ubuntu 10 to 12
2. Reinstall Zimbra 8 for Ubuntu 12
3. Upgrade Zimbra 8 to 8.5 for Ubuntu 12
4. Upgrade Ubuntu 12 to 14
5. Reinstall Zimbra 8.5 for Ubuntu 14
6. Upgrade Zimbra 8.5 to 8.7 for Ubuntu 14
7. Upgrade Ubuntu 14 to 16
8 Reinstall Zimbra 8.7 for Ubuntu 16

Comment: Won't the time to migrate 2TB of data be much longer than upgrading on the same server? Thus more acceptable to the users? Also, the migration MUST be on the same version to avoid incompatibility issue.